# Is a conversion.properties file always necessary for Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, type-conversion

I'm reading Struts 2 In Action, and, on the chapter five, a conversion.properties file is created to demonstrate data transfer for multivalued parameters. It includes this line:

```
Element_weights=java.lang.Double
```

And there's a list that does not use generics in the Action class:

```
List weights;
```

I replaced all this with just

```
List<Double> weights;
```

and the type conversion seemed to work just fine. Are there any drawbacks to using generics, any reason for what the authors of the book are doing?

edit: I kept reading and, in fact, generics work, and the authors even recommend it. Why they haven't used it in the first place still puzzles me, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types of conversion entries are only needed in pre-generics environments. Definitely use generics if at all possible.

Comment: What intrigues me is that generics exist since 2004. The book was released on 2008. Doesnt' make sense.

Comment: My guess is that it is there to help the few poor souls that are still on 1.4. Some large business are slow to adopt new technologies.